# Site Collection Name same as prefix?

Tags: site, collection

I am trying to create a site in our sharepoint environment called 'IT' however we already have a prefix for 'IT'.

So for example we have setup http://teams.ourdomain.com/IT/ITServiceDesk

However we want to create a root IT Team Site on http://teams.ourdomain.com/IT - when we try this says we cannot do this as 'IT' is already used a prefix.

Workaround please??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the IT managed path is set up. If ITServiceDesk is a site collection, then the IT managed path is a wild card inclusion and any number of site collections can be created under the IT managed path. However, a site collection cannot be created at /IT.

If having a root site at /IT is needed, then you'd need to convert the wild card managed path to an explicit inclusion, create a site at IT, then copy the ITServiceDesk site into /IT as a subsite.